# How to typecast in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following loadMore function that returns Promise<Project[] | Folder[] | undefined>.

```
const items = await loadMore();
```

I want to cast the type of items to Folder[]. How do I do that using typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would offer that it's better to discriminate the items of the array with the following inline type-discriminator used as the predicate in `Array.filter`

```
const folderItems = items?.filter(
    (v: Folder | Project): v is Folder => /* is v really a Folder? true/false */
);
```

to give you either an array that you can be sure contains only `Folder` items, or `undefined` if `items` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```ts
const items = await loadMore() as Folder[];
```

However, it's safer to [discriminate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) the union.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it :

```
const items: Folder[] = loadMore()
```